# Se detectó un posible valor Request.Path peligroso en el cliente (<).] usando ajax en asp mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Intento cargar una vista modal de [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) con el `ActionResult` devuelto por medio de [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax), estoy usando este script:

```
    $('#btnCreate').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#btnCreate').attr('data-modal', '');
    $('#btnCreate').attr('data-toggle', 'modal');

    var params = {
        companyId: $('#companyId').val(),
        proveedorId: $('#proveedorId').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Banco/Create")',
        data: params,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (result) {
            $('#myModalContent').load(result, function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({
                    /*backdrop: 'static',*/
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');
                bindForm(this);
            });
        }
    });

    $('#btnCreate').removeAttr('data-modal');
    $('#btnCreate').removeAttr('data-toggle');

    return false;
});
```

Pero al ejecutarlo me muestra el siguiente mensaje de error:

> [HttpException (0x80004005): Se detectó un posible valor Request.Path
>   peligroso en el cliente (<).]
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +9807804
>   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +53

Si alguien tiene alguna idea de como resolver este problema le estaré agradecido si me comparte la información.

Comment: Por tu pregunta anterior entiendo que los valores companyId y proveedorId son numéricos por lo que no debería darte este problema. Revisa con las herramientas de desarrollo de tu navegador (generalmente se abren pulsando F12) que la información que estás enviando al servidor sea correcta. Puedes ver las peticiones realizadas en la pestaña Red/Network de las herramientas de desarrollo

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar el problema deberias aplicar un `encode` al contenido de los textbox que envias por ajax

[HTML-encoding in JavaScript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery)

[Escape HTML using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020714/escape-html-using-jquery)

La idea es aplicar un replace de los caracteres como ser `<` por `&lt;`

entonces cuando defines

```
var params = {
    companyId: htmlEscape($('#companyId').val()),
    proveedorId: htmlEscape($('#proveedorId').val())
};
```

teniendo por ejemplo la funcion

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
  return String(str)
    .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
    .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
    .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
    .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
    .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```